# It's possible to forward/reverse a track with Apple EarPods remote?

Tags: iphone, ios, remote-control, ear-phones

I am using my EarPods for running, but i can't forward or reverse any track with remote on EarPods. I always pick the iPhone from my pocket. Much like it happens in the e-books..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To **forward** a track, **double-press and hold** the middle button of the remote.
- To **reverse** a track, **triple-press and hold** the middle button of the remote.